# Apex Batch class for the array for records from Inbound REST Service

Tags: rest, batch-file, salesforce, apex, bulk-load

I have to upsert around 80 K records on daily nightly batch. I was thinking of using the REST service to get the records in an array, and create a batch apex to upsert them in Salesforce. I will not be getting the CSV and is out of question. 
Will I able to iterate the record of array in batch apex start method to process them in batch?
Is this right approach? 
Is there a better approach for getting the large amount of records and process them in bulk?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. Please edit your Q.

Answer (score 0):

The REST API upserts records to the database.  You cannot use it to pass data to a batch apex class.  You can use the REST API to save data and then later have a batch class perform additional operations on that data but why bother if you can just have that logic performed as part of your upsert.

Comment: Thanks Matt, for the response. I understand that we can use the REST API to upsert records. I want to upsert in bulk mode. How do I achieve that?  Any thoughts?

Comment: The Bulk API can be used to upsert large batches of data.  https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Loading_Large_Data_Sets_with_the_Force.com_Bulk_API